# UIColor extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicolor

I have extended UIColor class in objective-c
the header file is like this:

```
@interface UIColor (ColorDecision)
+ (UIColor*) directOrLegacyWithColor;
+ (UIColor*) changeColor;
@end
```

implementation:

```
#import "UIColor+ColorDecision.h"

@implementation UIColor (ColorDecision)
 + (UIColor *)directOrLegacyWithColor {
     UIColor *color;
     UIColor *returenedColor = self.changeColor;
     color = LoginsManager.getSharedInstance.isDirect ? returenedColor : [UIColor self];
     return color;
}

 + (UIColor *)changeColor{
     UIColor *newColor;
     if (self == Color_C7) newColor = Color_Direct;

     return newColor;
}
@end
```

I get an warning from compiler at the below line 'Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UIColor *' from 'Class''

```
color = LoginsManager.getSharedInstance.isDirect ? returenedColor : [UIColor self];
```

I know the problem is some how related to the pointers but I don't get what should I do.

## EDIT

Thanks to manishharma93 comment I resolved the first problem now when I want to use the specified method it seems that the methods are not visible.

I defined my colors in a global header file like this:

```
#define Color_C7           [SharedUtility colorWithHexString:@"FF6A00"] // orange
#define Color_Direct      [Utility colorWithHexString:@"313d53"] // Color for direct
```

This is the implementation of the 'colorWithHexString' function in the Utility class:

```
+(UIColor *)colorWithHexString:(NSString *)hexString {
NSString *colorString = [[hexString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"#" withString: @""] uppercaseString];
CGFloat alpha, red, blue, green;
switch ([colorString length]) {
    case 3: // #RGB
        alpha = 1.0f;
        red   = [SharedUtility colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 0 length: 1];
        green = [SharedUtility colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 1 length: 1];
        blue  = [SharedUtility colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 2 length: 1];
        break;
    case 4: // #ARGB
        alpha = [SharedUtility colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 0 length: 1];
        red   = [SharedUtility colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 1 length: 1];
        green = [SharedUtility colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 2 length: 1];
        blue  = [SharedUtility colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 3 length: 1];
        break;
    case 6: // #RRGGBB
        alpha = 1.0f;
        red   = [SharedUtility colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 0 length: 2];
        green = [SharedUtility colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 2 length: 2];
        blue  = [SharedUtility colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 4 length: 2];
        break;
    case 8: // #AARRGGBB
        alpha = [SharedUtility colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 0 length: 2];
        red   = [SharedUtility colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 2 length: 2];
        green = [SharedUtility colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 4 length: 2];
        blue  = [SharedUtility colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 6 length: 2];
        break;
    default:
        LOG(@"WARNING: tried to set color from string: %@ BUT string should be  a hex value of the form #RBG, #ARGB, #RRGGBB, or #AARRGGBB ", hexString);
        return nil;
        break;
}
return [UIColor colorWithRed: red green: green blue: blue alpha: alpha];
}
```

now when I want to use my extension function for example like this:
self.background = Color_C7. directOrLegacyWithColor
the 'directOrLegacyWithColor' function is not visible

Comment: Change "self" to "[UIColor self]". Warning will go

Comment: @manishsharma93 the problem is fixed thanks. but now I have another problem when I want use for example Color_C7. directOrLegacyWithColor the method 'directOrLegacyWithColor' is not visible

Comment: Can you update your answer with values for Color_C7 & Color_Direct. So that it would be easy for me to figure out the cause. And I will write the above comment in answer, do accept it if it solves your cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you method, Change "self" to "[UIColor self]".

```
+ (UIColor *)directOrLegacyWithColor {
     UIColor *color;
     UIColor *returenedColor = self.changeColor;
     color = LoginsManager.getSharedInstance.isDirect ? returenedColor : [UIColor self];
     return color;
}
```

Comment: I accepted your answer but in the edit I added another one

Comment: @taratandel Thanks for accepting answer. But I don't think you can access UIColor class methods on macros. So what you can do is, create an object of UIColor and get value into it, for eg., UIColor *color = [UIColor directOrLegacyWithColor];. And then you can use these colors as you want

Comment: can I do it like this ? + (UIColor *)directOrLegacyWithColor: (UIColor *)color {
    UIColor *newColor;
    UIColor *returenedColor = self.changeColor: color;
    newColor = LoginsManager.getSharedInstance.isDirect ? returenedColor : [UIColor self];
    return newColor;
}

+ (UIColor *)changeColor: (UIColor *)color{
    UIColor *newColor;
    if (self == Color_C7) newColor = Color_Direct;
    
    return newColor;
}

Comment: Yes. Try it this way.

Comment: I'm still getting an error: No member named 'changeColor' in 'struct objc_class'

Comment: Try to change this line "self.changeColor: color" with  "[self changeColor:color]"